# SQL Developer, assigning text values to a column

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I know I have to be missing something small here but I can't figure it out. I need to assign a text to a field of selected rows.

```
update exampletable
   set examplecolumn = 'A'
 where column1 LIKE 'Y' 
   and column2 IS NULL 
   and column3 =0 
   and column4 IS NULL;
```

Any help is appreciated

**edit:  I should have clarified that 'examplecolumn' doesn't change after running this. All the records that meet the 'where' criteria still have null values in the examplecolumn

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: please share the error message?

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have clarified that 'examplecolumn' doesn't change after running this. All the records that meet the 'where' criteria still have null values in the examplecolumn.

Comment: Do you get any results if you do `select * from exampletable where {{ same where }}`?

Comment: Yes, the select * returns the records from the {where} query properly

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your update statement. Try to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can reproduce your problem on our end.

Comment: Seems like it worked, but what was/is still hanging me up is when I run: `select count(*) from exampletable where examplecolumn like 'A';` I get 0 records returned. That's why I originally thought the first update statement wasn't working.. any ideas to why that would return 0 records?? Thank you all for your input.

Comment: Maybe a missing `COMMIT`?

Comment: I have the `COMMIT` in my query I didn't include it in the post though.

Answer (score 0):

After all, it turned out that the real question is

> when I run: `select count(*) from exampletable where examplecolumn like 'A';` I get 0 records returned. That's why I originally thought the first update statement wasn't working.. any ideas to why that would return 0 records??

That's because you misused `LIKE` operator and/or provided invalid search string. Have a look at this example:

```
SQL> select * From dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL> select count(*) From dept where dname like 'A';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0    --> because no row contains exactly letter A in DEPT column

SQL> select count(*) From dept where dname like 'A%';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1    --> using the wildcard, it found ACCOUNTING

SQL>
```

In other words, your query searched for string that contains **exactly** letter `A`. I presume that code you posted in the question is just an example, while your *real* code updates column to something else, a little bit longer string. Because, if it was really `A`, query would have returned it:

```
SQL> insert into dept (deptno, dname) values (1, 'A');

1 row created.

SQL> select count(*) From dept where dname like 'A';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1   --> now it found DNAME = A

SQL> select count(*) From dept where dname like 'A%';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         2   --> wildcard found both DNAME = A and ACCOUNTING

SQL>
```